# SQL error Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got the following error when I change the PlanningDate period. Because of one PlanningTime has more than one "ProgrammeTitle, Title". I tried to change it as join, but can't get my expect result. Please help

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>   >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
select pt.PlanningTime,
       (SELECT (LTRIM(RTRIM(ProgrammeTitle+':'+Title))) 
        FROM Planning 
        where ChannelID = '34'
         and CONVERT(char(8),PlanningDate,112) between '20130101' and '20130107'
         and pt.PlanningTime = PlanningTime
         and DATEPART(dw,PlanningDate)=1) AS Title1, 
       (SELECT (LTRIM(RTRIM(ProgrammeTitle+':'+Title))) 
        FROM Planning 
        where ChannelID = '34'
          and CONVERT(char(8),PlanningDate,112) between '20130101' and '20130107'
          and pt.PlanningTime = PlanningTime
          and DATEPART(dw,PlanningDate)=2) AS Title2 
FROM PlanningTime pt 
where pt.ChannelID = '34'
  and CONVERT(char(8),pt.PlanningDate,112) between '20130101' and '20130107'
```

Comment: Please tag dbms product. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: One or both sub-selects return more than 1 row. Either correlate (incl. a condition to outer level table), or do joins instead.

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag because the syntax looks like SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that your sub query returns more than one value and so you cant query the result this way. You must find some other way to query your results as per your table structure. Just think that any one of the sub-query in your query returns more than one result, how your select would work? That's it.

Comment: rinesh, can you help me to modify the coding? The users want to show all records under the PlanningTime

Comment: You can use Joins to join `Planning` and `PlanningTime` tables on `ChannelID` . It is simple and straight forward.

Comment: rines, I tried to modified it to use join, but it can't outputed the result for what I expected! The users want to show all records which they inputted! The coding I showed it's part of the coding, the users want to show the date in column & time in row

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can get all the rows using `outer apply`:

```
SELECT pt.PlanningTime, p1.Title1, p2.Title2
FROM PlanningTime pt OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT (LTRIM(RTRIM(ProgrammeTitle+':'+Title))) 
      FROM Planning 
      WHERE ChannelID = '34' and
            CONVERT(char(8),PlanningDate,112) between '20130101' and '20130107' and
            pt.PlanningTime = PlanningTime and
           DATEPART(dw, PlanningDate) = 1
     ) p1 OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT (LTRIM(RTRIM(ProgrammeTitle+':'+Title))) 
      FROM Planning 
      WHERE ChannelID = '34' AND
            CONVERT(char(8),PlanningDate,112) between '20130101' and '20130107'
            pt.PlanningTime = PlanningTime and
           DATEPART(dw,PlanningDate)=2
     ) p2
where pt.ChannelID = '34' and
      CONVERT(char(8),pt.PlanningDate,112) between '20130101' and '20130107';
```

This will get rid of your error.  However, I'm guessing that the results are not exactly what you want.  Your question doesn't specify what you want, so this should set you on a better path.

Note:  You should use built-in date/time functions when working with date/times.  You are converting them to strings, which is simply a bad idea.  You don't need to do that and it affects performance.

Comment: Gordon, This is sample coding which easy to ready & understand. My program coding has define the Date Time for input parameters. Your modified coding can't show the result which I expected! It's showing a lot duplication records even of I use DISTINCT. And some Title show in wrong column. The users what to show the Date in column & Time in row. Some fields should be BLANK because of some time period don't has record.  I try to use inner join, it also show the wrong result.